# Typescript compile error with import statements

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with compiling my Typescript with imports of node modules. In my quite old code I have structured my classes/interfaces in (internal) modules/namespaces, for example:

```
module My.Namespace.Models {
   export interface IModelInterface {
      myProperty: string;
   }
}

module My.Namespace {
   import IModelInterface = My.Namespace.Models.IModelInterface;
   
   export class MyClass {
      private model: IModelInterface;
   }
}
```

This code compiles fine. If I want to use imports of npm modules (for example signalr) in my code and add an import for the module, the code won't compile and gives me an error message with the old import for the interface (Namespace 'My.Namespace' has no exported member 'Models'):

```
import {HubConnection} from "@microsoft/signalr";

module My.Namespace {
   import IModelInterface = My.Namespace.Models.IModelInterface;
   
   export class MyClass {
      private model: IModelInterface;
   }
}
```

Is there a possibility to use this two import approaches together?

Comment: read: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html

Comment: I have read the documentation, but I have the same problems with using the namespace keyword instead of the module keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work, if I remove the module/namespace in the second file:

```
import {HubConnection} from "@microsoft/signalr";
import IModelInterface = My.Namespace.Models.IModelInterface;

export class MyClass {
  private model: IModelInterface;
}
```